# Connect different agent type Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have 5 agents - bus, transformer , generator, load , line. I have a requirement where i need dynamically connect the above agents.

I have written the following code, where i am trying to connect for example bus [2] and generator[5]. The connections are not random but based on a circuit, which i am dynamically reading through a text file.

```
for (int l = 0; l < busList.size(); l++) {
for (int k = 0; k < generatorList.size(); k++) {
                    if (generatorList.get(k).getBusNumber()==busList.get(l).getBusNumber()) {

busList.get(l).getBusID().connectTo(generatorList.get(k).getGenID());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can someone help with the connection part. I cannot have a generic list because I need the agent attributes for other functionalities as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *busList* and *generatorList* are collections containing entries of type *Bus* and *Generator* respectively, which both are derived of type *Agent*, the following code should work for connecting:

```
busList.get(l).connectTo(generatorList.get(k));
```

I don't know why you used *getBusID* and *getGenID* which I assume return an integer. If they really return a *Bus* or a *Generator* object it should work as you already wrote. In this case you would need to provide us the error message or the exact problem that you have.